# How to parse the XML using DOM parser

Tags: android, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

how to parser the following XML using `DOM PARSER`

```
<Result>
<Status>OK</Status>
<All_BookDetails>
<BookAuthor>Mohammadi Reyshahri</BookAuthor> 
<BookRating>0</BookRating>
<BookDescription>Islamic belief and ideology</BookDescription>
<DatePublished>May  1 1992 12:00AM</DatePublished>
<BookTitle>Are You Free or Slave</BookTitle>
<BookID>171</BookID>
<BookCode>EN171</BookCode>
<BookImage>1.jpg</BookImage>
<TotalPages>164</TotalPages>
</All_BookDetails>
</Result>
```

i want to get the values of `BookAuthor`, `BookRating`, `BookDescription`,`DatePublished`, `BookTitle`, `BookID`, `BookCode`, `BookImage` `TotalPages`

how can i do this. I tried to parse the above XML selecting `All_BookDetails` as parent node but `nodelist` returning me the 0 in length

thanks

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/. A place where you can start.

Comment: in which device and its API level? I smell it just same issue which I'm facing, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870304/failed-to-fetch-xml-data-from-res-in-android-3-0-and-above)

Comment: Please show some code you tried

Comment: I am so sorry guys i was commenting a mistake. i was not selecting the <All_BookDetails> as the parent. It was bug here in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting XML DOM element

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    dbf.setCoalescing(true);
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }

    return doc;

}
```

then I tried this and its worked

```
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(XMLString);
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("All_BookDetails");

            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(0);
            BookRating = (Integer.valueOf(parser.getValue(e,
                        "BookAuthor")));

            BookTitle = parser.getValue(e, "BookTitle");
            BookAuthor = parser.getValue(e, "BookAuthor");
            BookPublishDate = parser.getValue(e, "DatePublished");
            BookDescription = parser.getValue(e, "BookDescription");
            bookID = parser.getValue(e, "BookID");
            bookCode = parser.getValue(e, "BookID");
            bookPageCount = parser.getValue(e, "TotalPages");
```